# How to prove that $\frac{2 x}{(1-x)^3}$ is real-analytic using the Taylor remainder function $R_n (x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis

I have been trying to prove that $\dfrac{2 x}{(1-x)^3}$ is real-analytic using the Taylor remainder function $R_n (x)$. I tried to bound from above $R_n (x)$, but each time the bound I found just diverges to infinity. I would like to understand whether it is possible to find an appropriate upper bound (a one that converges), or does this way actually leads to no convincing result?

Comment: Can you show us your attempt?

Comment: Note that’ll only converge with $|x|<1$. Hard to guess where you are making a mistake without more work.

Comment: @Eric my problem is indeed because |x|<1.

Comment: @Eric  my problem is indeed because |x|<1. I calculated R_n (x)=  (f^((n+1) ) (c))/(n+1)! x^(n+1)=  (2c+n+1 )(n+2)!/〖(1-c)〗^(n+4) *x^(n+1)/(n+1)!=  (2c+n+1 )(n+2)/(1-c)^(n+4) *x^(n+1), where c is a real number between 0 and x. The problem is with the 1-c in the denominator which diverges as n -> infinity and also the n+2 in the nominator.

Comment: Restrict $x$ to $[0,1/2)$. Then $c< 1/2$, so  you have convergence on for $x<1/2$. You probably need to do something smarter to show convergence all the way up to 1.

Comment: Tbh, it’s much more straightforward to show uniform convergence directly i.e. via Cauchy Hadamard or the ratio test.